# Moving Laravel project from Windows 7 to Raspbian Jessie

Tags: laravel, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I created a Laravel webapp running on a homestead vm on my Windows 7 machine. I want to take this webapp and move it over to my raspberry pi so it's easily accessible from my other devices, since my decsktop doesn't have a direct connection to my router.

I have my pi setup with apache2 and Laravel all the way to the point that if I create a Laravel project in /var/www using 
    php ~/composer.phar create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel project
Then I can access it through the URL:
    192.168.1.232/project/public

However, when I pull the webapp I created on the homestead machine through get and place it in /var/www on the pi, I get a page isnt working, currently unable to handle request error.

Does anyone know what files I would need to change/git ignore to develop Laravel on my windows machine and then pull certain versions to my pi without creating errors?

Comment: you need to copy the whole project, not only www, because www is just a tiny part of laravel, that is available through get. so, maybe zip/tar everything and unpack on your pi.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I was able to fix this issue by looking at the git ignored files. Two necessary files, /vendor and .env were being ignored when I pushed my project to git. All I did was recreate the .env file in my project directory on my pi, and move a copy a vendor file over from a project I created on the pi, and my webapp started to work.